# app crashes when using kABPersinPhoneProperty

Tags: iphone, xcode, abaddressbook

I am trying to get all the phone number from the Phone Book of iPhone. But my app crashes as soon as I try to fetch the number using kABPersonPhoneProperty. The code snippet is here

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate(); 
NSMutableArray *allPeople = (NSMutableArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook); 
int nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook); 
CFRelease(addressBook);

for(int i=0; i < nPeople; i++ ){

    ABRecordRef person = [allPeople objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *name = @"";
    CFTypeRef fName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    CFTypeRef lName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person , kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    NSString *number = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);

    if ([number length] > 0) {
        if(fName != NULL)
        {
            if (lName != NULL) {
                name = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fName] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
            }
            else {
                name = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fName] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
            }
            NSLog(@"Number==>%@ ",number);
        }
    }
    if (fName != NULL) {
        CFRelease(fName);
    }
    if (lName != NULL) {
        CFRelease(lName);
    }
    if (multi != NULL) {
        CFRelease(multi);
    }
}

[allPeople release];
```

I am unable to figure out the error in this. I am also releasing everything even then it is not running smoothly.

I am even getting potential memory leak when running build and analyze for the code part

```
ABMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person , kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    NSLog(@"Number===>%d" , ABMultiValueGetCount(multi));
```

Please help me out to come.

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you put the crash log please. It will give very clear idea to people out here, which will get you the help real fast.

Comment: the worst part is app crashes without any warning or message

Comment: @devsri: crashing without notifying the user is the Apple way.

Comment: Have you set the NSZombieEnabled environment variable?

Comment: I also see that you are releasing allPeople object which seems to be autoRelease object, try to comment that line and run the code again.

Comment: thanks for the response but commenting the line did not work!!
 and NSZombieWnabled I have not tried, can you please suggest me how to use it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response. I have figured out the solution fot the problem here. I did not release number variable thinking that the reference was passed as reference but it is copied to the returned location, hence need to release number after the usage.

thanks again for all the responses!!